# Edit files in a Virtualbox VM (vagrant box) from host

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I was messing with systemd in my Vagrant box and I think I did something wrong since the box won't boot anymore.  What I need to do is to remove certain files under `/etc/systemd` in my Vagrant box.  However since I can't boot it, I have to remove those files from the host, but I don't know how to do it.

The VM provider is virtualbox.  Both the host and the guest are ubuntu 15.04.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you login from virtual box in your vm ?

Comment: The vm won't even boot anymore so unfortunately no...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating a new VM but I'm fairly certain that this would work: you just mount the virtual disk file (`.vmdk` in my case) as a hard drive and make the fix.  For different formats of virtual disks you need different tools to mount them, which I'm not going to cover here.

Answer (score 1):

- option 1: you can try to add `vagrant ssh -c 'cmd to run'` in your vagrant file, but as you said it really does not boot, I give it really *low chance to success*.
- option 2: create a new VM and add the hard drive from the old box to the new box (add new hard drive from existing disk), boot it and you might need to mount the new hard drive then you should be able to access your data so make the change in your `/etc/systemd` or whatever files you need and save. once you have made all your fix, you should be able to reboot from the old vm.

Comment: Good answer - have my vote. Note you can use a live Linux distro such as Knoppix for option 2, you are not obliged to do a full install.